# What is GST RhoA fusion protein?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins

Would you please explain to me what GST RhoA fusion protein means and how it differs from RhoA protein? I am a kind of doing an experiment using this protein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GST is glutathione-S-transferase, an enzyme that binds reasonably tightly to glutathione. It is often used as a tag to purify proteins of interest. In your case, GST has been fused to RhoA most likely so that you have some means to purify it by applying it to a glutathione conjugated column. See [here](https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/gst-tagged-proteins-production-purification.html) for more information.